# TCPClient: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient, zebra-printers

Trying to write to network stream to a socket but getting the following error:

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Application has a concurrent list of print jobs, so while we have something to print, check tcp client is connected, if not connect, get stream, write to stream and flush.

Sample code is as follows:

```
/// <summary> Print via TCP </summary>
private void PrintViaTcp(object a)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Printing via TCP...");
    var labelData = a as LabelData;            

    // Send data to the label printer
    SendToLabelPrinter(labelData.Commands, labelData.PrinterAddress, labelData.Port);

    Debug.WriteLine(" -> Printed labelId : {0}", labelData.LabelId);
}

/// <summary> Send the native command to the label printer </summary>        
public void SendToLabelPrinter(string commands, string address, int? port)
{                        
    //Connect to tcp client if a connection does not exist
    if (!TcpClient.Connected) TcpClient.Connect(address, port ?? 9100);

    //Get the network stream
    var stream = TcpClient.GetStream();

    // Send command strings to printer
    //stream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(commands), 0, commands.Length);
    stream.Write(Encoding.GetEncoding(850).GetBytes(commands), 0, commands.Length);

    //Flush the buffer on the network stream
    stream.Flush();           
}
```

This works for small prints jobs < 100 prints, but when I go over 100, the errors randomly occurs missing prints.

Comment: It seems like a concurrency problem. You should check how many concurrent jobs can be handled by your printer server

Answer (score 0):

Best way to analyze and to find root cause of TCP or Network issues which occurs randomly is to start looking at Wireshark which can provide more insight to what is being sent and how connection is refused in between

Also As in your code there is no timeout setting on TCPClient please try setting higher `**timeouts**` setting when sending or receiving more data amount.. which could be the problem. Again with wireshark you will know every details how connection got closed and who initiated it.. just look for FIN flag

[Wireshark download](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html)

Answer (score 0):

The network stack can process one connection at a time and can queue up 8 or so connections before it will start to refuse connections. If you send it many individual connection requests you need to account for the refusal and back off until the printer can handle the request.

Another option is to create a print handler that you send all of the print jobs to.

When first request comes in open connection to the printer.
As new requests come in add them to the queue.
If connection has not been used for a minute close down the connection.